# Printing queue of queues elements

Tags: c++

Hello I have the following function which prints the elements of a queue

```
 template<typename T>
 void queue<T>::print()
{
T x;
while(!empty())
{
    pop(x);
    cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

}
I have made a queue of queues like this

```
 queue< queue<int> > my_queue_of_queues =queue< queue<int>>();
```

but how can I print all the elements of the queues of "my_queue_of_queues"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but how can I print all the elements of the queues of "my_queue_of_queues"?

**Option 1** Use `operator<<` instead of `print`.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,  queue<T> const& q)
{
   // Don't modify the input.
   // Create a copy and modify the copy.
   queue<T> copy(q);
   while(!copy.empty())
   {
      T x;
      copy.pop(x);
      out << x << " ";
   }
   return out;
}
```

**Option 2** Update `print` and call the `operator<<` function to re-direct the implementation.

```
template<typename T>
void queue<T>::print()
{
   cout << *this;
}
```

**Option 3** Update `print` and call the `operator<<` function to re-direct the implementation but pass a `std::ostream` to `print`. Don't assume `cout` in `print`.

```
template<typename T>
void queue<T>::print(std::ostream& out)
{
   out << *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your `print()` implementation, simply define an `operator<<(std::ostream&, const queue<T>&)` overload and it will *just work*:

```
template <typename T>
auto& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const queue<T>& x)
{
    x.print();
    return os;
}
```